# Build a Laravel project

Tags: php, debugging, compilation, compiler-errors, laravel-5

**Compile complete project:**
While working with Laravel is there a way to **Compile** & **Build** the whole project in one shot?

Which in turn returns all the exceptions suppose to be occurring in the complete project.

Just like .net and java which has some IDE that compiles the whole project before using it and returns some exceptions or syntax errors.

**Line by line compiling/debugging:**
In Dotnet/Java we can put break point and than execute the code line by line to see the flow of code. This is very useful in case of logical error, is there something out of the box which we can use in Laravel/PHP?

I am using NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Because php editor not a super IDE so if you want debug in PHP, you can use phpStor and try install xDebug plugin.

Comment: Will that debug the code wherever there is syntax error in the overall project.